# Automatically zip attachments on Mail getting sent

Tags: macos, mail.app, automation, zip

How can I have a single file or several files that I dropped into an email on Mac, automatically become a zip file before getting sent?

Comment: I don't think you can drop files into mail app and then zip them... I was thinking there could be a plugin that does something like that, like maybe just when you try to attach multiple files, the plugin could ask you if you wanted to zip them or something, but I couldn't find any plugins like that.

Comment: You could definitely string together actions in Automator that takes in files, zips them and then opens the new message window and adds the zip as an attachment. This could be just a shortcut or a context menu item (Automator Service) that then hands over the selected files in Finder... or an App icon (Automator App) that sits next to your Mail app in the Dock where you would drag the files. — Here's one example: https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/Email_Attachments_with_Automator. That article is pretty old, but it looked to me like nothing has changed.

Comment: @Joonas That is a good idea! Better than mine after the question was edited. Please post it as an answer!

Comment: I thought about it and I was pretty tempted to just copy & paste that article to my answer... But I think it would be better if you answered it yourself. I believe you were able to do it based on the article and so maybe there would be more worth in you answering your own question with what worked for you rather than me copying something off the internet. Not that I'm expecting you to have done it much differently...  — I think you have to wait like 8 hours after posting your own answer to be able to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Attaching the folder with all the files in it would zip them. But all Mac users wouldn’t see the zip but the folder itself.